# Untitled goose game - no more pint glasses

Tags: untitled-goose-game

At the Pub in Untitled Goose Game there is a task to steal a pint glass and drop it in the canal. This is somewhat tricky because the pint glass is easily broken.  After attempting several times, all the pint glasses are now broken and I don’t seem able to complete this task.

Nearly every task in the game can be retried over and over but this task doesn’t seem to have an obvious way to have unlimited retries.  The only way I can get the pint glasses to reset is to quit the game and reload, at which point most items are reset.

Is there any other way to get more pint glasses for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to some Reddit post, such as [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/untitledgoosegame/comments/dcxt9m/help_smashed_all_the_beer_glasses_how_can_i_chuck/), there should be a waitress who will place another pint glass:

> The waitress pulls another one out of the cart when all three are broken.

Another [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/untitledgoosegame/comments/ddhnch/help_i_broke_all_the_pints/):

> the glass on the metal cart respawns pretty regularly

You may just need to wait!

Comment: it looks like the key must be to not have the waitress in view because we hid nearby for 10 minutes to no avail.  Thanks!